# Puppet Class Default Parameter/Variables

Tags: puppet

I am using a custom ENC and would like to be able to have classes default parameters to variables higher in scope.

This allows me to set a variable in the top scope, node scope, wrapper class scope, etc and the value will be picked up as a default parameter for a class.

This then allows me to also still set the parameter at the class definition. The one downside to this approach is that a class could potentially pick up an "unsafe" default although I feel that it is an unlikely scenario.

Has anyone else looked at solving a problem such as this and is this overall a good idea or a bad idea?

**custom_enc.yaml**

```
classes:
  rsyslog::client:
     port: 1234
parameters:
  server: my-rsyslog-server
```

**manifest/server.pp**

```
class rsyslog::client(
  $server => $server,   # $server = $server || undef
  $port   => $port ? {  # $port = $port || '514'
    ''      => '514',
    default => $port
  }
) {

  if !defined($server) { fail "server must be defined" }

  notify { "The server is ${server}": }
  notify { "The port is ${port}": }

}
```

Comment: What version of puppet are you using? Related: Have you looked into hiera? It will take care of (and pretty much eliminate) setting the default values, ensuring a parameter is set, etc. I can provide an example if you like.

Comment: Hiera supports automatic parameter settings, so if your yaml has a key "rsyslog::client::server", then the $server parameter of rsyslog::client will default to that value. (Just be aware that automatic parameters don't merge array or hash values.)